# JavaFX How to check 2 observable values and run code if they match conditions, and how to get pair of values from custom jfx window

Tags: javafx, lambda, observable

I have very simple window for changing password from javafx dialog collection - i use custom dialog example to build it (http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/). Questions are bolded in below code:

```
    Dialog<Pair<String, String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.setTitle("Password change");

    ButtonType ButtonTypeSavePassword = new ButtonType("Save", 
    ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
    ButtonType ButtonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", 
    ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
    //dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(loginButtonType, 
    ButtonType.CANCEL);

    // Create the username and password labels and fields.
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

    PasswordField pass1 = new PasswordField();
    PasswordField pass2 = new PasswordField();

    grid.add(new Label("Enter new password"), 0, 0);
    grid.add(pass1, 1, 0);
    grid.add(new Label("Re-enter new password "), 0, 1);
    grid.add(pass2, 1, 1);


    Node saveButton = 
    dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonTypeSavePassword);
    saveButton.setDisable(true);

    Platform.runLater(() -> pass1.requestFocus());
```

**//??? How to check two observable values at once(if pass1.length>0 and pass2.length>0) with lambda expression and change saveButton to enable?**

```
    dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
    if (dialogButton == ButtonTypeSavePassword ) {
    return new Pair<>(pass1.getText(), pass2.getText());
    }
    return null;
    });

    Optional<Pair<String, String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();

    result.ifPresent(usernamePassword ->
    {

        System.out.println("Username=" + usernamePassword.getKey() + ", 
    Password=" + usernamePassword.getValue());
    });
```

**//??? How can I put values from the pair into 2 Strings defined outside the Custom Dialog JFX Window (not to system out like above)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to check two observable values at once(if pass1.length>0 and pass2.length>0) with lambda expression and change saveButton to enable?

You can do this a number of ways.

With a listener on both password fields:

```
saveButton.setDisable(true);
ChangeListener<String> passwordListener = (obs, oldPW, newPW) -> 
    saveButton.setDisable(pass1.getText().isEmpty() || pass2.getText().isEmpty());
pass1.textProperty().addListener(passwordListener);
pass2.textProperty().addListener(passwordListener);
```

Or with a binding, which you can do with `Bindings.length(...)`:

```
saveButton.disableProperty().bind(
    Bindings.length(pass1.textProperty()).isEqualTo(0)
    .or(Bindings.length(pass2.textProperty()).isEqualTo(0))
);
```

or with `Bindings.createBooleanBinding()`:

```
saveButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
    pass1.getText().isEmpty() || pass2.getText().isEmpty(),
    pass1.textProperty(), pass2.textProperty()));
```

(and there are other options too).

> How can I put values from the pair into 2 Strings defined outside the Custom Dialog JFX Window (not to system out like above)?

First, please don't combine multiple questions into a single post. It makes it harder for other users to find answers to questions that might have already been asked.

It's not really clear what you mean here. You can just define `setUsername(...)` and `setPassword(...)` methods in the class of whatever object you want to pass the data to, and call those methods:

```
someOtherThing.setUsername(usernamePassword.getKey());
someOtherThing.setPassword(usernamePassword.getValue());
```

Comment: James_D - thank you very much for working solution - it's very easy to understand now :). Should i split my questions into 2 posts to make it easy to find for another users in future?